# can't get ar_track_alvar on Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wanted to get a marker detector like ar_track_alvar but after running

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-ar-track-alvar
```

it says the package can not be found. It is not also available from source code link

https://bitbucket.org/sniekum/ar_track_alvar.git

May you guide me how to download it or even I appreciate if you know any other marker detection package in ROS?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57792/can%27t-get-ar_track_alvar-on-fuerte/) by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The debbuild page says that 0.3.0 should be in ros public, have you tried updating your debian info by running:

```
  sudo apt-get update
```

As for a source checkout, I believe it was recently moved to github: https://github.com/sniekum/ar_track_alvar

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reza Ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1696/reza-ch/) on 2013-03-12**:
I was trying the source from bitbocket.org not from github.com
and I have a ubuntu 10.04 as operating system. Why I tried to get it from source was cause I couldnt not get it from command line. after updating apt-get, the sudo apt-cache search can not find it even. Thanks